# PHP integration with PayPal IPN returning empty POST data

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

i have looked through the other threads on here and am yet to find a solution for the issue i have. I am using the "IPN Simulator" on the paypal sandbox website, i put in the url to my ipn processing script which sends me an email notifying me of what happened. Every request that the IPN sends has empty POST data, any idea what i could be doing wrong here?

The following piece of code is what i am using to fetch the POST data, any help is much appreciated!

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
```

Comment: Try `if(empty($_POST)){echo "empty";}else{print_r($_POST);}` If you're getting "emtpy" then you aren't receiving any post data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try testing this with a test sandbox seller and buyer account.  Set the IPN up on your test sandbox seller account, and go through and make a test purchase.  Once you have done this, you can log into the seller account and go to your IPN history and actually see the IPN string that got sent out.  This will help you to verify that atleast an IPN POST is being sent out.  It should also show you if it was successful, or if it failed or is in a retrying status.  If it failed, it will show you the status code that your server returned back if your server is responding back with something.  You could also try using the IPN sample script found at https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623  I have tested the PHP one and it was working for me.

Comment: I updated my script to this one and the code seems alot newer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added rm hidden field into form? Without rm field,It may return empty data.